# Ошибка при добавлении записи в админки laravel "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

При добавлении записи через админку в ларавел выдает ошибку. Раньше добавлялось все, сегодня просто перестало работать, ничего не менял.

```
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($v->fails()) return back()->withErrors($v->errors())->withInput();

    $boolean_exceptions = ['enable', 'type'];
    $file_exceptions = ['images'];

    $result = $this->crudClass->insert($this->info->modelName, $id ,$request, null, $boolean_exceptions, $file_exceptions);
    $item = $result['message'];
    $item->alias = Transliteration::make(lang_filter($item->title), ['type' => 'url', 'lowercase' => true]) .'-'.$item->id;
    $item->save();

    if ($result['status'] == 'ok')
        return redirect('/admin/'.$this->info->url)->with('message', 'Запись обновлена');
    else
        return back()->withErrors($result['message']);
}

public function enable(Request $request)
{
    $result = $this->crudClass->enable($this->info->modelName, $request);

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Показывает ошибку в строке

```
 $item->alias = Transliteration::make(lang_filter($item->title), ['type' => 'url', 'lowercase' => true]) .'-'.$item->id;
```

Сама ошибка 
**"Trying to get property 'title' of non-object"**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: dd($item) что показывает?

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут все придельно ясно. У вас в `$item` приходит либо не объект либо вовсе `null`. А вы пытаетесь достучаться к `$item->title`. Вот и вам говорят что невозможно взять значение из пустого обїекта.
Попробуйте посмотреть что у вас в этой строке приходит:

```
$item = $result['message'];
```